# Significant time difference in CUDA while using bitwise shift instead of mod

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I'm relatively new  to CUDA programming and I was testing different, simple kernels to see the difference in execution time.

I have two kernels, that do the same for me:

```
__global__ void mathKernel2(float *c)
{
int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
float ia, ib;
ia = ib = 0.0f;

    if ((tid / warpSize) % 2 == 0)
    {   
        ia = 100.0f;
    }
    else
    {   
        ib = 200.0f;
    }

    c[tid] = ia + ib;
}
```

and another one:

```
__global__ void mathKernel4(float *c)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float ia, ib;
    ia = ib = 0.0f;

    int itid = tid >> 5;

    if (itid & 0x01 == 0)
    {   
        ia = 100.0f;
    }
    else
    {   
        ib = 200.0f;
    }

    c[tid] = ia + ib;
}
```

I compile it with -g -G to get rid of optimization and get:

```
mathKernel2 <<< 8192   32 >>> elapsed 0.000259 sec 
mathKernel4 <<< 8192   32 >>> elapsed 0.000103 sec
```

Why the difference is so big?

Comment: that's less than a millisecond, is it really so significant?

Comment: The integer modulo operator is known to be slow on GPUs

Comment: @1blustone maybe not in that case, but ovarall it can make difference

Comment: Performance analysis on unoptimized (`-G`) code isn't really sensible.

Comment: Integer division is also very slow. The first code has both.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if (itid & 0x01 == 0)
```

reads as:

```
if (itid & (0x01 == 0))
```

which is evaluated at compile-time to `false` and one of the branches is removed.

Bitwise binary operators have a rather low priority in C/C++, as well as CUDA.

Comment: I think this optimization is likely to only occur in fully optimized code, not debug code.  OP's question specifically wants to understand behavior in debug mode.  If you take this code and compile it to a cubin with `-G`, and then do `cuobjdump -sass` on it, you will see both floating point value assignments and both branches evident in the code, controlled by a predicated `BRA` instruction.  It's not obvious to me that this is an explanation of behavior in the unoptimized case.

Comment: Right, didn't pay attention to the -G flag. In that case the integer modulo may be the problem, not being optimized to shr. That being said, the two kernels do not do the same thing.